# Unable to install MikTex on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, certificates

I uninstall MikTex because texstudio can't update package automatically. I want to install it again. But I got this error instead when I launch `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunderme/texstudio/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                    
Hit:5 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:6 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Ubuntu:/debbuild/Ubuntu_20.04  InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:7 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                
Ign:2 https://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/systems/win32/miktex/setup/deb focal InRelease           
Err:11 https://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/systems/win32/miktex/setup/deb focal Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses insecure algorithm.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 158.75.62.5 443]
Ign:10 https://cvmrepo.web.cern.ch/cvmrepo/apt focal-prod InRelease
Hit:12 https://cvmrepo.web.cern.ch/cvmrepo/apt focal-prod Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried `sudo apt install ca-certificates` but it failed.
This also doesn't work [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)
The result from there:

```
~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason

~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Ubuntu:/debbuild/Ubuntu_20.04  InRelease
Hit:3 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunderme/texstudio/ubuntu focal InRelease       
Hit:5 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit:7 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Ign:6 https://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/systems/win32/miktex/setup/deb focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease              
Err:10 https://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/systems/win32/miktex/setup/deb focal Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses insecure algorithm.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 158.75.62.5 443]
Ign:8 https://cvmrepo.web.cern.ch/cvmrepo/apt focal-prod InRelease             
Hit:12 https://cvmrepo.web.cern.ch/cvmrepo/apt focal-prod Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Now I can't install it again. Help?

Comment: A 14.04 (trusty) source seems unwise: `http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty`. Consider deleting it.

Comment: @N0rbert OP wants to install MiKTex, and possibly added a (non-functional) MiKTex repo for that. Purging the MiKTex repo won't help OP to install MiKTex.

Comment: You can install ppa-purge with `sudo apt install ppa-purge`. But that would remove the problematic MiKTeX repo (and that would not automatically install MikTeX)

Answer (score 1):

nothing works. but lol... I can install it again after ignoring it for one week.

```
~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunderme/texstudio/ubuntu focal InRelease       
Get:4 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]      
Hit:6 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Ubuntu:/debbuild/Ubuntu_20.04  InRelease
Get:7 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]   
Hit:10 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                             
Get:8 https://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/setup/deb focal InRelease [2 030 B]
Get:11 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [841 kB]
Ign:9 https://cvmrepo.web.cern.ch/cvmrepo/apt focal-prod InRelease
Get:12 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [434 kB]
Get:13 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [264 kB]
Get:14 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [746 kB]
Get:16 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [555 kB]
Get:17 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [302 kB]
Get:18 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 468 B]
Hit:15 https://cvmrepo.web.cern.ch/cvmrepo/apt focal-prod Release              
Get:19 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1 768 B]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24,2 kB]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [58,2 kB]
Fetched 3 554 kB in 1s (2 409 kB/s)                                           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/source/Sources' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

The problem was simply

```
E: The repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

just let it go and wait.